# Checking data before delete in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with deleting data in my project..
I have two table database without any relationship

Form's table

```
Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('FormName', 200);
        $table->string('GroupID', 100)->nullable();
        $table->integer('EditorType');
        $table->integer('LanguageID')->nullable()->default(1);
        $table->integer('PageTemplateID')->nullable();
        $table->integer('GadgetID')->nullable();
        $table->string('Categories', 200)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Content Setting's table

```
Schema::create('content_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('language_id');
        $table->integer('gadget_id');
        $table->string('ContentSettingName', 100);
        $table->text('ContentSettingValue');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $form = Form::findOrFail($id);
    $pages = Form::where('GroupID', $form->GroupID)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $homepage = ContentSetting::where('language_id', $form->LanguageID)
                              ->where('gadget_id', $form->GadgetID)
                              ->where('ContentSettingValue', $form->id)
                              ->pluck('ContentSettingValue')->first();
    if(!in_array($homepage, $pages)){
        $deletePages = Form::where('GroupID', $form->GroupID)->delete();
    }

    return response()->json($homepage);
}
```

When I store data into database, I will store 2 rows of data directly. because in my form's table, I have column language ID, and the 2 rows of data have the same GroupID.. The problem is when I want to delete the data.

The `forms.id` is connected with `content_settings.ContentSettingValue`. So, when I have stored the data, I can choose one of the data to be `default homepage`. If I click delete button to the data where is default homepage, it will occur an alert('You can not delete the default homepage'), but If I click delete button to the data where is not the default homepage, but It has same GroupID with the default homepage. It will delete two rows of data (in the other word, the default homepage will be deleted too). How can I handle it if I check that if one of the data is default Homepage and the other one is not default homepage, but they have same GroupID, I can not delete both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I have found, If you have the simpliest answer or the shortest way. Please add your answer here, It can help the others that have the same problem ;)

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $form = Form::findOrFail($id);
    $pages = Form::where('GroupID', $form->GroupID)->get()->pluck('id');
    $homepage = ContentSetting::whereIn('ContentSettingValue', $pages)
                              ->count();
    if($homepage < 1){
        $deletePages = Form::where('GroupID', $form->GroupID)->delete();
    }

    return response()->json($homepage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the $id to delete the row which should be provided in the parameter.
In my understanding, the destroy function is provided an id to check whether it is deletable. The function will do delete if not default, and will not do delete if it is default homepage. So simply use the id to delete:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $form = Form::findOrFail($id);
    $pages = Form::where('GroupID', $form->GroupID)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $homepage = ContentSetting::where('language_id', $form->LanguageID)
                          ->where('gadget_id', $form->GadgetID)
                          ->where('ContentSettingValue', $form->id)
                          ->pluck('ContentSettingValue')->first();
    if(!in_array($homepage, $pages)){
        $deletePages = Form::whereId($id)->delete();
    }

    return response()->json($homepage);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your way, but I still get the same issue.. When I delete the data which has the same groupID with default home page, It still delete both of them. I have already found the answer, you can check it. But, thankyou for your answer, I appreciate it ;)